# Get userId with Javascript SDK with Backendless

Tags: javascript, backendless

The backendless [JavaScript](https://backendless.com/documentation/users/js/users_get_current_user.htm) documentation says you retrieve the current user object using `var currentUser = Backendless.UserService.getCurrentUser();`

I did not find any reference to what are the propertes of the user object or how to get the objectId or ownerId from this object.

I am looking for an answer to get the user's objectId

```
var userObjectId = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the objectId of the user, you do this:

```
var userObjectId = userObj.objectId;
```

or this:

```
var userObjectId = userObj[ "objectId" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This method returns only the current logged in users objectId:

```
var userObjectId = Backendless.UserService.loggedInUser();
```

I was not able to find this method on the online vendor documentation but is reference several times on the support forum.